# Prove $\sqrt{\frac32}$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I first suppose for contradiction that if it's rational, then it can be written as a form of $\frac{p}{q}$, where it's in the lowest term.
Then it becomes $\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}=\dfrac{p}{q}$.
Then I square both side and get $\frac{3}{2}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$.
I'm confused about what I should do next to get the contradiction.
Can anyone please give me a hint?

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof of irrationality of other roots?

Comment: Can you prove $\sqrt 6$ is irrational? Because $\sqrt{6}=2\sqrt{3/2}.$

Comment: [One option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with how to prove square root of prime numbers are irrational. This is my first time to prove the square root of a fraction is irrational.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $2p^2=3q^2$ we have $3q^2$ is even, which means that $q$ is even, $q=2r$. Then $2p^2 =3 (2r)^2$, then $p^2=2(3r^2)$, so $p$ is even. This contradicts the fact that the fraction is in its lower terms.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Write $2p^2=3q^2$. Now take a prime factor, $p_1$, of $p$. What can you say about $p_1$? You already know that it can not divide $q$.

After you find out the condition for $p_1$, do the same for a prime factor, $q_1$, of $q$.

Comment: I'd suggest explaining the $(p,q)$ GCD notation for readers that may be unfamiliar.

Comment: If $p=1$ you can't take a prime factor of $p$. Although trivial, it's a case you need to consider.

Comment: @jjagmath, you are right , however, this is only a hint and not a full solution. It is the OP's job to handle these minors.

Comment: @Arnaldo Good point.